# Where to store Application Data in Windows 7 and Vista

Tags: c#, windows-7, uac, application-settings, special-folders

My application needs to, like most, store data.  The application was previously used on XP only where it would store the data in `Program Files`.  Now that our customers are moving to Windows 7 I had to upgrade it so that it stored the data in a new folder.  I opted for the `ApplicationData` folder as I thought I would be allowed access without needing UAC at all.

Now on some Windows 7 machines this is fine, but on others access to the folder fails, presumably because of permissions, but when ran with Administrator privelidges the program works fine.

Am I using the wrong folder or are these cases outliers? In either case what is the best practice for this kind of thing?

I am using the following C# `SpecialFolder` to get the AppData folder location.

```
System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` is per-user and roams. That doesn't sound like what you want. You appear to want machine wide settings and so should use `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`.

Because `CommonApplicationData` is shared between all users, the default access control is limited. By default standard users cannot write in this location. The recommended practise is to create a sub-folder of `CommonApplicationData` at installation time and assign it suitably permissive access control settings.

Comment: Will I require UAC to access `CommonApplicationData` like I do `ApplicationData`? Also wouldn't that mean data is shared between all users on the same PC?

Comment: @Chris "Wouldn't that mean data is shared between all users on the same PC?" Well yes, but you were formerly storing it in `Program Files` which is machine-wide.

Answer (score 2):

David is right.
As far I know, there's also some difference if you deploy your app via ClickOnce or Installer: the first allows a few subset of permissions than the normal installer.
I must confess I'm not an expert on that.

Of sure, Program Files is the *worst* place to store data, even since XP.

Comment: You mean Program Files, ProgramData the name of the common appdata folder on NT6

Comment: Ya!...My head is going bad...Thanks Anders!