# Windows 7/Vista storing files in application directory

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

are there any restrictions regarding storing files in application folder under windows 7/vista ?

Where in users directory should application data files be stored ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to store Application Data in Windows 7 and Vista](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116911/where-to-store-application-data-in-windows-7-and-vista)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my apps that store files in app folder work fine under vista/7 (default configs).
So I think yes.

You can store files in 2 places

1. users home directory - location can be read from environment variable USERPROFILE
2. application data folder - can be found in env. var. APPDATA

Answer (score 0):

You can store arbitrary data in your application's installation directory (most likely "Program Files" or "Program Files (x86)"), but you will have to have Administrator privileges to do so (which can be very annoying for users, especially if they have UAC enabled). Once you have the privileges, there are no further limitations.

For more detail see the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116911/where-to-store-application-data-in-windows-7-and-vista) Ken White linked.