# How to Create a file and folder in the Program Files using C#

Tags: c#

I have a program created using c# which will resides at the c:\program files folder. 
I will get error if I am going to run this part

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("db/MyDatabase.sqlite");
```

I already read about User Account Control thing here http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx but i really don't have any idea on how to do it..

My program will be in C:\program files\my program\db\MyDatabase.sqlite

Comment: Try and run your program as an admin.

Comment: i do.. but it I always get an error.. and it says something like "collecting error ..."

Comment: Why not use the folders Windows provides for that kind of stuff? %APPDATA% and Documents?

Comment: What is the exact exception?  Does the `db` subfolder already exist, and, if not, will SQLite automatically create any subfolders as necessary when creating the file?

Comment: @kat0r so you mean it will become like this `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\my program\db\MyDatabase.sqlite` ? or i will replace Username with variable and others?

Comment: Instead of saying it says "something like" please copy and paste [the exact error message](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276.aspx) in to your question.

Comment: The usual way would be `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\YourCompanyName\ProgrammName\MyDatabase.sqlite`. But you do not need the special privileges to write there, that you would need to write to the ProgramFiles folder.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie `db` sub folder doesn't exist.. if (!File.Exists("db//legal_dept.sqlite"))
            {
                SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("db/MyDatabase.sqlite");
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Connected";
            }

Comment: Program Files is the worst directory where to store data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116911/where-to-store-application-data-in-windows-7-and-vista

Comment: My Program has stop working Windows is collecting more information about this problem. This might take several minutes... @ScottChamberlain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the AppData folder - you should not save such stuff in ProgramFiles anyway:

```
var dir = Path.Combine(Environment
    .GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "MyProgram");
if(!Directory.Exists(dir))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(Path.Combine(dir, "MyDatabase.sqlite"));
```